# hide mesh from an armature

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

How can I hide a mesh of an armature?

When I click on hiding the object it only hides the bones but not the mesh.

How can I do that?

[image]

[image]

Thank you,
Luelaes

Comment: Hello, what do you mean exactly? Are you trying to hide the armature or the mesh? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I want to hide the whole armature inclusive the mesh of the guy, not only the bones. :-)
when I click the hide button, only the bones are invisible but not the mesh of the armature.

Comment: you need to select the character object as well and press H (or in the Outliner, click on the arrow next to the armature name so that you can see the character object and click on its visibility)

Comment: ohh man, that was so easy. XD
Thank you very much. :-)